# Find missing files from array

Tags: php

I'm trying to find out what files from my collection are missing, They are numbered from '0001.rar' up to '2500.rar', I used this to put all the names into an array:

```
$files = glob("/*.rar");
```

How can I work out which of the files are missing from the folder?

Comment: So are you trying to find all of your `.rar` files and see which are missing (i.e. 1234.rar and 2499.rar do not exist)?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

You can construct the array of expected filenames using `array_map` and `range`:

```
<?php

array_diff(
  array_map(function ($i) {
    return sprintf('%04d.rar', $i);
  }, range(1, 2500)),
  glob('*.rar')
);
```

The above will yield an array of just the missing names.

Comment: So do i need to put this in a forloop with my files, then that would be $i ?

Comment: @Exoon depends, what are you doing with the for loop?

Comment: Sorry think i was confused, What is the $i for in your code ?

Comment: @Exoon it's for constructing the list of expected files. I'm using `array_map` instead of a `foreach` loop to construct the array.

Comment: Ok, sorry i don't really understand that well, i changed my orignal script a little the array doesn't have .rar in anymore it just shows the 4 digit number like this: Array ( [0] => 0501 [1] => 0502 [2] => 0504 [3] => 0505 the array is called $numbers, What do i need to change on your code?

Comment: @Exoon remove the `.rar` from the `sprintf`

Comment: I tried that but it just get me a blank white page.

Comment: @Exoon look in your apache log